# Transparent Text with background GIF not working on Chrome Mobile version 79.0.3945.73 React

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a transparent text with a background gif.  It works on desktop chrome and safari.  works on safari mobile but the title does not show on chrome mobile.  The links appear but the title does not.  On desktop and Safari Mobile the title shows.

```
const Menu = () => {
  return (
    <section className="menu">
      <h1 id="menuTitle">The Pinellas Ale Trail</h1>
      <section className="menuLinks">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home Page</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/BreweryMap">Brewery Map</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/AdminPage">Add info</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </section>
    </section>
  )
}

.menu {
    margin: auto;
    background-image: url(../src/Images/Mandolorian.gif);
    /* color: transparent; */
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    text-align: center;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#menuTitle {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Milonga', cursive;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following information from https://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts

Known Issues:

iOS Safari has buggy behavior with background-size: cover; + background-attachment: fixed;
iOS Safari has buggy behavior with background-size: cover; on a page's body.